# Xero : OAuth2: Python3: Example Code to get the refresh token

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, xero-api

Xero has changed its API to require OAuth2 connections instead of OAuth1.

I had a working solution in OAuth1, but the examples for Oauth2 are scarce at best, but mainly for web sites.

I'm another developer who managed to create an Oauth1 solution, that successfully worked as a machine to machine solution with no web server involved.

Xero has some examples that run in Postman, that easily work in my test environment.

I'm attempting to reproduce the postman action of refreshing the token in Python3.

My basic code below is where I currently am:

```
#client_id = "xxxxx"
#client_secret = "xxxxx"
callback_url = "https://api.xero.com/connections"
re_directURI = "https://developer.xero.com"
scopes = "offline_access accounting.contacts accounting.transactions"

refresh_url = "https://identity.xero.com/connect/token"

access_token = open('AccessToken.txt').read()
old_refresh_token = open('RefreshToken.txt','r').read()


# Refresh Token code...

import requests

#def refresh_xero_token(refresh_token):

headers = {
'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
data = {
'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
'refresh_token': old_refresh_token,
'client_id': client_id,
'client_secret': client_secret
}
print(data,headers)
response = requests.post(refresh_url, headers=headers, data=data)

#return response.json()
print(response.text)
```

I have so far failed to find an example that works without a web server, just using python to communicate with the Xero servers to transfer local data into the Zero API.

Using xoauth,.exe (windows) to get the access_token, and then in postman I can run the examples for refresh token, connections, invoices etc to the demo company.

and I believe just being able to replicate these examples will provide me with what I need to get a working solution.

currently with this python code I only get
{"error":"invalid_request"}

So, clearly I am missing something.

I'll class myself as a newbie with Python or Oauth2, but have chosen this path due to my previous success with an Oauth1 connected solution.

I would ask the Xero developer community, but I'm writing this for a user of our software to push data into their Xero accounts, and so for testing I only have a trial account, which does not give me access to the Xero developer community.

Which by itself is really annoying.

Xero support seems of little use also, I tried.

If there is anyone out there able to assist, that would be fabulous.

Thank you in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 1):

As additional information, I can then also use this connection to, for example create a contact in Xero:

In this example the irContact is a SQLAlchemy row of data from a SQL table.

def create_contact( connection, irContact, access_token):

```
#Setup new contact
address1 = {"AddressType": "POBOX"}

if irContact['addressline1'] is not None: address1.update({"AddressLine1": irContact['addressline1']})
if irContact['addressline2'] is not None: address1.update({"AddressLine2": irContact['addressline2']})
if irContact['addressline3'] is not None: address1.update({"AddressLine3": irContact['addressline3']})
if irContact['addressline4'] is not None: address1.update({"AddressLine4": irContact['addressline4']})
if irContact['city'] is not None: address1.update({"City": irContact['city']})
if irContact['region'] is not None: address1.update({"Region": irContact['region']})
if irContact['postalcode'] is not None: address1.update({"PostalCode": irContact['postalcode']})
if irContact['country'] is not None: address1.update({"Country": irContact['country']})
if irContact['attentionto'] is not None: address1.update({"AttentionTo": irContact['attentionto']})

#print (address1.values())

addresses = []
addresses.append(address1)

phones = []
if irContact['phonenumber'] is not None:
    phone1 = {"PhoneType": "DEFAULT"}
    #phone1.update({"PhoneType": "DEFAULT"})
    if irContact['phonenumber'] is not None: phone1.update({"PhoneNumber": irContact['phonenumber']})
    if irContact['phoneareacode'] is not None: phone1.update({"PhoneAreaCode": irContact['phoneareacode']})
    if irContact['phonecountrycode'] is not None: phone1.update({"PhoneCountryCode": irContact['phonecountrycode']})

    phones.append(phone1)
    #print (phone1.values())
    

if irContact['mobilenumber'] is not None:
    phone2 = {"PhoneType": "MOBILE"}
    if irContact['phonenumber'] is not None: phone2.update({"PhoneNumber": irContact['mobilenumber']})
    if irContact['phoneareacode'] is not None: phone2.update({"PhoneAreaCode": irContact['mobileareacode']})
    if irContact['phonecountrycode'] is not None: phone2.update({"PhoneCountryCode": irContact['mobilecountrycode']})

    phones.append(phone2)
    #print (phone2.values())
    

contact = { "Name": irContact['name'],
             "ContactNumber": irContact['contactnumber'],
             "AccountNumber": irContact['accountnumber'],
             #"ContactStatus": "ACTIVE",
             "FirstName": irContact['firstname'],
             "LastName": irContact['lastname'],
             #"EmailAddress": irContact['emailaddress'],
             "Addresses": addresses,
             #"Phones":phones
            }

contacts = [contact]
#print(contacts)

contacts_url = "https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts"

headers = {
  'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}",
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'xero-tenant-id': tenant_id,
}
data = {
'Contacts': [contact],
}
#print(data)

try:
    response = requests.post(contacts_url, headers=headers, json=data)
except Exception as err:
    print("ERROR! Contact: %s" % (str(err) ))
    print(response.text)
    return 0

#print(response.text)

results = response.json()

if 'Contacts' in results:
    newcontacts = results['Contacts']
    for newcontact in newcontacts: break

    query = "update xero_contact set errortext='', ContactID='%s' where id=%d" % (newcontact["ContactID"], irContact['id'])
    connection.execute(query)

    query = "update xero_invoice_header set ContactID='%s' where OurContactID=%d and (InvoiceID='' or InvoiceID is null ) " % ( newcontact["ContactID"], irContact['id']  )
    connection.execute(query)
```

I believe, with this amount of information, anyone can be capable of creating their own Xero machine to machine interface...
Realising that other records can be read and created using minimal tweaks to the header and or data element of the requests call.

I found the lack of this information so very frustrating, if people can find this, it may help them in future.

Answer (score 0):

After using the xoauth application and setting up the connection, I have since found that with the refresh token, running this function keeps the connection up and running.

```
def refresh_xero_token():
    refresh_url =       "https://identity.xero.com/connect/token"

    old_refresh_token = open('RefreshToken.txt','r').read()

    tokenb4 = f"{client_id}:{client_secret}"
    basic_token = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(tokenb4.encode()).decode()

    headers = {
      'Authorization': f"Basic {basic_token}",
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
    data = {
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token': old_refresh_token
    }

    try:
        response = requests.post(refresh_url, headers=headers, data=data)

        results = response.json()
        open('RefreshToken.txt','w').write(results["refresh_token"])
        open('AccessToken.txt','w').write(results["access_token"])

    except Exception as err:
        print("ERROR ! Refreshing token error?")
        print(response.text)
```